# How Can ExtractGrok use multiple regular expressions?

Tags: apache-nifi, logstash-grok

I have a Kakfa topic which includes different types of messages sent from different sources.

I would like to use the `ExtractGrok` processor to extract the message based on the regular expression/grok pattern.

How do I configure or run the processor with multiple regular expression?

For example, the Kafka topic contains INFO, WARNING and ERROR log entries from different applications.

I would like to separate the different log levels messages and place then into HDFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Using `ExtractGrok` processor, use **Partition Record processor** in NiFi to partition as this processor

1. Evaluates one or more RecordPaths against the each record in the
   incoming FlowFile.
2. Each record is then grouped with other "like records".
3. Configure/enable controller services

   RecordReader as GrokReader

   Record writer as **your desired format**

Then use PutHDFS processor to store the flowfile based on the loglevel attribute.

**Flow:**

```
1.ConsumeKafka processor
2.Partition Record
3.PutHDFS processor
```

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/131320/using-partitionrecord-grokreaderjsonwriter-to-pars.html) link describes all the steps how to configure PartitionRecord processor.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/191760/create-dynamic-partitions-based-on-flowfile-conten.html) link describes how to store partitions dynamically in HDFS directories using PutHDFS processor.

Comment: I can only enter 1 grok expression. How do I enter multiple grok expressions?

Comment: As you can keep 1 grok expression to match the LogLevel then in PartitionRecord add new property as matches to your level record path..


Then PartitionRecord processor will keep all the like records into respected flowfiles.

Comment: if the record does not match the first partition record, I should chain it to the second partition record to allow the flow file to pass through each from expression specified in the processor?

Comment: PartitionRecord does **dynamic partitions** on the flowfile based on the record path provided. **No attribute** will be added if there is no record path in the message. You can use **RouteOnAttribute** processor to filter out (or) **UpdateAttribute** processor to add attribute with some default value to it.

Comment: how do I extract specific fields from the output?

Comment: You can use **ExtractText(add new property with matching regex to the specific field)/EvaluateJson(if the input is in Json format) processor/s** to extract specific fields. If you are thinking to Query on specific fields in the flowfile content then use QueryRecord processor.
Reference:  https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html